# VirtualBox Guest Additions or Linux bug?

Tags: installation, virtualbox

I am not to sure if this is a bug, but it certainly has been an annoying aspect for some time now with VBGA. When installing the guest additions, one mounts the Guest Additions. This usually happens flawlessly, but one is not able to interact with any of the files with the Guest Additions 'media' unless one explores the file in the file viewer (like double-clicking the disk that appears).

Am I wrong in thinking that because the disk is mounted it should be listed under media without need for this unnecessary step?

PS. There is need for a new "Guest-Additions" or "VBGA" tag for questions like these no? (Can't create own tags yet).

Comment: What OS is on the guest system? On the host system? What VBox version?

Comment: @Piskvor Almost all VirtualBox version 3 & 4 up and almost any unixes. Some modern Linuxes such as OpenSuse install a default version, but I am referring to the manual method of installing via the terminal.

Comment: Hmm...interesting. I think this may be a bit of a confusion in terms: you need to first *attach*, on the host, the virtual CD to the guest's virtual CD drive, and then  in the guest *mount* the CD that's in the drive. Are you saying that the guest doesn't automatically mount inserted CDs? I'm pretty sure that's the default for CD media on most Linuxes...

Comment: @Piskvor Seems logical except that the disk is clearly attached and explorable using the file browser and in some cases you can see it on the Desktop.

Comment: Seeing it on the desktop != mounted ; in fact, that's what I'm talking about: my machine shows the CD icon on the desktop as soon as the CD is inserted, but *only after I open the icon with Nautilus* does it mount the CD's filesystem. I think this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to not be a bug but my misunderstanding.